# h2o autoencoder errors trend positively on test data

Tags: deep-learning, h2o, autoencoder

I am using H2o with R to train an autoencoder using h2o.deeplearning. My training data used to fit the model is 10000x1000 so there is a real possibility of overfitting (because I have only 10 data cases per variable). The purpose of training the autoencoder is to detect outliers in the test data.

What I am finding is reasonable performance on the training data (MSE~0.015) but a strong trend upwards in errors on the test data.

[image]

I have experimented with both dropout and l1/l2 regularization parameters in an attempt to generalize the learning (that is not have the model too precisely memorizing the input data). I have:

```
anomaly_model <- h2o.deeplearning(
x = colnames(obs_h2o),
training_frame = obs_h2o,
activation = "RectifierWithDropout", 
autoencoder = TRUE,
hidden = c(100),   
reproducible = FALSE,  
standardize = TRUE,
seed = 7,
mini_batch_size = 2,
epochs = 10,          # number of times whole dataset is iterated
input_dropout_ratio   = 0.3,
hidden_dropout_ratios = 0.9,
average_activation    = 1.9,
sparse = TRUE,   
l2 = 1e-3
)
```

I have tried tweaking parameters but this increase in error with time on the test data persists.

Any ideas related to this strange occurrence?